# is JS command `new Date()` the same across different devices and timezones?

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have a server running in America and Europe, and I run `new Date().getTime()` on both machines at the same time, would they both return sameish timestamp?

or could 1 be drastically different?

What affects that return, is it the time configured on the machine executing it?

Comment: Did you try looking at the documentation for getTime before asking?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @charlietfl What is "the documentation" that you refer to? (Curious what you consider to be the authoritative ECMAScript docs)

Comment: MDN is very reliable and well regarded https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date

Answer (score 1):

getTime returns the number of milliseconds since January 1st 1970, UTC, so it doesn’t depend on the local machine time offset.

Answer (score 1):

[`Date.getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) returns the number of milliseconds since the [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). Regardless of the time zone configuration of either device, assuming that both devices have [synchronized clocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_synchronization), the values should be essentially identical.